# Merging Multiple Textures on a Single Model into one Mega-Texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, image

Every time I try to search for an answer or solution to this problem, it always comes up with the wrong information or something that is so outlandish that I don't understand.

I'm relatively new to Blender and I have a 3D model I downloaded that has a multitude of textures, from eyes, mouth, and body. I want to merge all these textures into one image so there can only be one texture file associated with it.

How can I do this? Do I need to compile the images in the *UV/Image Editor*, then re-UVmap the images in Blender? If so, could I just copy existing maps and somehow paste them onto the compiled version? Is there a wizard or file format that can do this for me?

Thank you for any help and I'm sincerely appreciative of any assistance.

Comment: Look into baking.

Comment: Ah, that was actually what I was looking for. Sorry for the thread, and this is resolved! Thanks.

Comment: If my answer helped, please consider accepting it by selecting the checkmark in its upper, left-hand corner. It would help me greatly and make me very happy! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

So to write up an answer, the OP needed baking.

Cycles baking is a relatively simple process as far as Blender goes, and is roughly like the following:

1. UV Unwrap a mesh with no overlapping *Islands*.
2. Add a new, blank image in the *UV/Image Editor*.

[image]

3. Go to the *Node Editor* and add an *Image Texture* node. Select the blank image. Do not make the image interact with the node tree in any way. Make sure the node is selected.
4. Go to the *Properties panel > Render tab > Bake dropdown* and select the following settings (for pure image textures).

[image]

You will then have an image with all the various *Image Textures* mapped onto it. You can incorporate this image with *UV Texture Coordinates* into one mega-object material.

Comment: Hi. I've recently come across the same problem as the OP. I have an OBJ+MTL with some PNG textures. I want to merge these PNG textures into one. Doing as instructed in your answer, the first step (UV unwrap) totally messed up the UV mappings of the original textures. I am not sure if it is because Blender is different from 4 years ago when it comes to baking. What should I do?